# Node - Mongoose update method issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to update and already queried document:

> In memory save way works fine:

```js
project.likers.push(profile.id);
project.set({
  likes: project.likes + 1
})
await project.save();
```

But I read in a blog that this way is slower as compared to using mongoose update method.

Since I am using multiple queries in this endpoint, I want to use mongoose update method for the same reason.

> Doesn't work

```js
project.update({ "$push": { "likers": profile.id }, "$inc": { "likes": 1 } });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`$push` : The operator appends a specified value to an array.

And there isn't command 'update'. There are two command for update and they are :

1. updateOne
2. updateMany

If you just want to update the existing field, you can use like below:

```
db.collectionname.updateMany({ "likers": profile.id }, { "$inc": { "likes": 1 } })
```

If you want more info, [check out.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/#update-operations)

Comment: I do not want to requery the document. I have already queried it, how to I update that?

Comment: You can use the query above.

Comment: So the above query does not query the database again as per the first object passed in the argument?

Comment: Every update statement doing what you say. First of all, it will find the document because it has to know which document will be updated, and then it will update them all.